# Grouping matrix rows by a column and plot3 the paths described by the rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, 3d, matlab-figure

I have the matrix `paths` with four columns: The first has a number which says to which `path` the row belongs to, the other three are the dimensions. I want to print the `paths`. I am doing it with:

```
for p = min(paths(1,:)):max(paths(1,:))
    path = paths(paths(:,1)==p,:);
    plot3(path(:,2),path(:,3),path(:,4),'Color','k');
end
```

With a little functional programming in mind, I would like to know: How can group the matrix `paths` by the first column and print the paths for each group?

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close to it. First, you need to loop through the values in the first *column* (not *row* as in your question), and the create a logical index for the taking only the relevant path and plot them (using `hold`):

```
paths = [randi(4,50,1) rand(50,3)]; % example data
for p = unique(paths(:,1)).'
  path = paths(:,1)==p; % a logical index for path p
  plot3(paths(path,2),paths(path,3),paths(path,4));
  hold on % to plot all the paths on the same axes
end
hold off % stop plotting on this axes
```

Here is an example for the output:

[image]